# How do I upload pem files to Twilio?

Tags: twilio, pem

Thanks in advance for helping me with this. I needed to create a TLS cert for my website and upload to Twilio. See the attached screenshot. It looks to me like I should be able to copy and past the file contents. My first instinct was to open the files, copy, and paste.

However, I cannot open the fullchain.pem and privatekey.pem files. I'm using a macbook pro. I found a possible way to copy the file using pbcopy, but I don't have permission. And, I'm not sure if that what's supposed to happen anyway.

Long story short, I have the correct files on my computer, but I have no clue how to actually get the cert and key into Twilio. Has anyone else done this?

Thanks!

[image]